# A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled on localhost?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I get the good 'ol "A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled." but only when I run my server locally, eg I dont get any errors on the deployed app?

So my question is, do I need to worry about it then? I cleaned upp the component in question to only use state coming in as props, but still the error occurs?

Regards

//NIC

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Can you add code examples of the components that trigger this warning? Also include the component where the prop is defined. In short, yes you should worry about this. These warnings are shown at the development stage that's why you are not seeing them in the deployed version.

Comment: Thanx guys @MantasAstra, I found the issue the state was set to 'undefined' in the parent-component and react didnt like that:)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own question, the state was set to 'undefined' in my parent-component and react did not like that, changed it to empty strings instead:)

```
    const [upd, setUpd] = useState({
    title: undefined, 
    description: undefined, 
    status: undefined
})
```